# Finding the edit distance of two strings with recursion

Tags: python, string

I need to use recursion to find the edit distance of two strings, i.e I give the function two arguments(each a different sring). And the function will find the least amount of changes required to change `s1` into `s2`. This is what I have so far:

```
def edit_distance(s1,s2):
    split1 = list(s1)
    split2 = list(s2)
    count = 0
    pos = 0

    if split1[pos] == split2[pos]:
        pos += 1
    else:
        pos +=1
        count += 1
        edit_distance(s1, s2)

return count #This should be the minimum amount required to match the two strings
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do, because I cannot tell, it seems extremely broken. Also there are at least two common definitions for string distance, one where only character substitution is considered (Hamming distance) and one where both substitution and deletion/insertion are considered. (Levenshtein distance) Finally please ask a specific question and explain what exactly happens/does not happen and what you tried so far to localize the problem.

Comment: Are you searching a recursive python implementation of the Levenshtain algorithm?

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: It's supposed to return the minimum amount of individual character changes required to turn s1 into s2. So if `s1 = 'a'` and `s2 = b` it should return 1

Comment: @erthalion I havent heard of that, Ill give it a look. Thanks

Comment: @Nabla when I print this with say the example I have two comments above I just get a recursion depth error. My reasoning in this piece of code here was that I keep going through every position in the strings to see if they match, if not then I add `1` to `count`. Which I thought should equal the amount of changes that would be needed to make the strings match

Comment: @Amon The main problem with your code is that you never actually go through the positions. You have `pos` always fixed to `0` and your recursion call is identical to the initial call, so you get infinite recursion.

Comment: @Nabla Yeah I figured that was the issue(no matter what it would return 0) but I couldn't figure out why. Thanks so much for your help, and annotating my code with the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I annotated your code to show you the code flow. I hope you understand now why you get the error:

```
def edit_distance(s1,s2):
    split1 = list(s1)    # Split strings into characters
    split2 = list(s2)
    count = 0            # This variable is local, it is not shared through calls to the function!
    pos = 0              # Same

    if split1[pos] == split2[pos]:   # pos is always 0 here!
        pos += 1                     # pos is incremented anyway, in if but also in else !
    else:
        pos +=1                      # See above
        count += 1                   # count is incremented, now it is 1
        edit_distance(s1, s2)        # recursive call, but with the identical arguments as before! The next function call will do exactly the same as this one, resulting in infinite recursion!

return count    # Wrong indentation here
```

Your function does not do what you want. In case you are talking about Hamming distance, which is not really clear to me still, here is a sample implementation assuming the lengths of both strings are equal:

```
# Notice that pos is passed between calls and initially set to zero
def hamming(s1, s2, pos=0):    
    # Are we after the last character already?
    if pos < len(s1):
        # Return one if the current position differs and add the result for the following positions (starting at pos+1) to that
        return (s1[pos] != s2[pos]) + hamming(s1, s2, pos+1)
    else:
        # If the end is already reached, the remaining distance is 0
        return 0
```